# R - What is the probability of a Value being *lower* than another value in a data frame

Tags: r, probability

Here is a minimal dataset for this question:

```
structure(list(DateTime = c("6-3-2016 09:00:00", "6-3-2016 09:05:00", 
"6-3-2016 09:10:00", "6-3-2016 09:15:00", "6-3-2016 09:20:00", 
"6-3-2016 09:25:00", "6-22-2016 10:35:00", "6-22-2016 10:40:00", 
"6-22-2016 10:45:00", "6-22-2016 10:50:00", "6-22-2016 10:55:00", 
"6-22-2016 11:00:00", "7-13-2016 10:30:00", "7-13-2016 10:35:00", 
"7-13-2016 10:40:00", "7-13-2016 10:45:00", "7-13-2016 10:50:00", 
"7-13-2016 10:55:00"), V1 = c(49.6, 49.56, 49.52, 49.66, 49.41, 
49.5, 49.67, 49.6, 49.69, 49.63, 49.75, 49.54, 45.92, 45.65, 
45.36, 45.46, 45.26, 45.25), Index = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), .Names = c("DateTime", 
"V1", "Index"), row.names = c(1492L, 1493L, 1494L, 1495L, 1496L, 
1497L, 5099L, 5100L, 5101L, 5102L, 5103L, 5104L, 9190L, 9191L, 
9192L, 9193L, 9194L, 9195L), class = "data.frame")
```

There are 18 observations in this dataset grouped in rows of 6 numbered 1 through 6 in the "Index" column.
The V1 value at Index "1" is always the "key".

Problem:
What is the probability of the V1 values at Indexes 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 being "lower than" the V1 Value at Index 1?

I hope the dataset is sufficient and my question clear.
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to first check the question: "Does the data give evidence that the observations at index 1 are different from  the others?"

Comment: You want to perform hypothesis testing then.

Comment: In what sense do you mean "probability"?  What is random about these data?

Comment: I though the question was unclear. Could not tell how many "probabiliteis were intended or which inequality comparisons should be made.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with a Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test, which is testing if the observations rank differently accross samples.

```
df = structure(list(DateTime = c("6-3-2016 09:00:00", "6-3-2016 09:05:00", 
"6-3-2016 09:10:00", "6-3-2016 09:15:00", "6-3-2016 09:20:00", 
"6-3-2016 09:25:00", "6-22-2016 10:35:00", "6-22-2016 10:40:00", 
"6-22-2016 10:45:00", "6-22-2016 10:50:00", "6-22-2016 10:55:00", 
"6-22-2016 11:00:00", "7-13-2016 10:30:00", "7-13-2016 10:35:00", 
"7-13-2016 10:40:00", "7-13-2016 10:45:00", "7-13-2016 10:50:00", 
"7-13-2016 10:55:00"), V1 = c(49.6, 49.56, 49.52, 49.66, 49.41, 
49.5, 49.67, 49.6, 49.69, 49.63, 49.75, 49.54, 45.92, 45.65, 
45.36, 45.46, 45.26, 45.25), Index = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), .Names = c("DateTime", 
"V1", "Index"), row.names = c(1492L, 1493L, 1494L, 1495L, 1496L, 
1497L, 5099L, 5100L, 5101L, 5102L, 5103L, 5104L, 9190L, 9191L, 
9192L, 9193L, 9194L, 9195L), class = "data.frame")

#Let's pick the last two columns
df = df[, c("V1", "Index")]

#A list comparing `V1` from `Index == 1` vs. other indexes. 
l.df = list()
for (i in 1:5)  l.df[[i]] = df[which(df$Index == 1 | df$Index == i+1),]

library(caTools)
#This calculates the
sol = sapply(l.df, function(x) colAUC(x$V1, x$Index))
names(sol) = paste(1, 2:6, sep = " vs. ")
print(round(sol, 3L))
#1 vs. 2 1 vs. 3 1 vs. 4 1 vs. 5 1 vs. 6 
#  0.722   0.556   0.556   0.556   0.778
```

These are the probabilities indexes ranks differ, aka. the probability that if you pick one sample from each distribution one of those will have a higher value than the other. 100% or 0% would mean there's total separation, therefore no overlap. [Read more about the test in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) and how it relates to AUC, which is the function I used instead of the statistic itself.

---

### A note

Almost forgot, this might not the probability that `V1`, `Index == 1` is lower than at other index, because in `caTools` only $\text {AUC} \geq 0.5$ is returned, transforming other results as needed.